# public function url

Tags: php, url

Estoy construyendo mi primer sitio web (soy muy nuevo en esto del coding).

En el formulario de creación de cuentas de usuario de mi sitio web, le pide a los usuarios las url's de sus perfiles sociales, pero solo funciona si escriben la parte que va **después** de `http//:www.` en vez de que simplemente copien y pegen la url de la barra de direcciones del navegador.

Este es el código que tiene el archivo `.tpl`;

```
public function isValidUrl($url) {
    return preg_match('|^[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
    //return (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED));
}

public function addScheme($url) {
    $scheme = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off')
              || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

    return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) === null ? $scheme . $url : $url;
}
```

Podrían por favor indicarme como modificar el código anterior para simplificarle a los usarios y solo copien y peguen la url tal cual aparece en la barra de los navegadores?

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para ello tendrias que cambiar la expresion regular, espero que esta te pueda servir (la probé y creo que cumple con lo que necesitas):

```
public function isValidUrl($url) {
    return preg_match('%^((https?://)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i', $url);
}
```

Comment: Funciona Gracias!

Comment: Listo, en ese caso por favor, califica la pregunta como resuelta @kmndz